# TableLayoutPanel: Delete Rows

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayout, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel which is filled with rows at runtime using a text file (get each row from the text file, and put it in cells contained in new rows).
Code Looks like this:

```
public static string UrlList= @"C:\Users\Berisha\Desktop\URLs.txt";
string[] UrlRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@UrlList);
        private void InitPaths()
    {
        int a = 0;
        int c = 1;
        while (a < UrlRows.Length-1)
        {   
            //new label
            var label = new Label();
            label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            label.AutoSize = false;
            label.Text = UrlRows[a];
            label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(22, 13);
            label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            TBP.Controls.Add(label, 3, c); //Add to TableLayoutPanel
            a++;
            c++;
        }
    }
```

Although I want to be able to manually edit the source,
so I wrote a method which would delete everything new created, but seem to be stuck here, because it doesn't work:

```
        private void clearPaths()
    {   
        int c = UrlRows.Length - 1;
        while (c <= UrlRows.Length - 1)
        {
            TBP.RowStyles.RemoveAt(c); //Remove from TableLayoutPanel
            c--;
        }

    }
```

*//The Code Stops at: TableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.RemoveAt(c);(while Debugging)
//and the error reads : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*
**Update: I managed to get out of the Error, my Problem now, after I say RemoveAt, nothing seems to be removed**
Does anybody know what it is that I could do?

Comment: OK, you mean it is stuck looping forever? Or what "doesn't work"? You need to be more descriptive. "it doesn't work" is probably the worst way you can describe a problem. Also, it's worth noting that you're incrementing `a` in both `clearPaths` AND `InitPaths`, but is only declared in `InitPaths`. Even if `a` were a global variable, which I hope it isn't with a name like that, it doesn't seem like you need to be incrementing it in `clearPaths`. I don't see how it could be, though, because there would be a name conflict with your declaration of `a` in `InitPaths`

Comment: Accidentaly forgot it in the second method while writing the question

Answer (score 5):

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

I Googled and Binged a solution to this problem for DAYS and couldn't find one.  I finally came with a solution that works!

```
tableLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();

while (tableLayoutPanel.RowCount > 1)
{
    int row = tableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        Control c = tableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(i, row);
        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(c);
        c.Dispose();
    }

    tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.RemoveAt(row);
    tableLayoutPanel.RowCount--;
}

tableLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
tableLayoutPanel.PerformLayout();
```

In my solution, I do not want to remove the first row.

Answer (score 2):

OK, looking at your second edit, I deleted my answer and am adding this new one.

I really doubt this works. Your while loop executes forever.

```
int c = UrlRows.Length - 1;
while (c <= UrlRows.Length - 1) //C will decrement forever and always be less than or equal
{
    TBP.RowStyles.RemoveAt(c); //Remove from TableLayoutPanel
    c--;
}
```

I'm not terribly sure what you want to do in that method, if you mean to remove everything, what you had initially would have worked.

```
int c = 1;
while (c <= UrlRows.Length - 1) //You now loop through all elements in TBP
{
    TBP.RowStyles.RemoveAt(c); //Remove from TableLayoutPanel
    c++;
}
```